# Setting XML element text nodes in Spyne

Tags: python, spyne

I use Spyne framework to provide SOAP web service. I need to return something very similar to

```
<MyReturnObject>                             
 <MyList>
   <MyElement Name="Value1">value2</MyElement>
   <MyElement Name="Value2">value3</MyElement>
 </MyList>
</MyReturnObject>
```

I tried the following

```
class MyElement(ComplexModel):
    Name = XMLAttribute(String)
class MyReturnObject(ComplexModel):
    MyList = Array(MyElement)
```

but that would result in

```
<MyReturnObject>                             
 <MyList>
   <MyElement Name="Value1"/>
   <MyElement Name="Value2"/>
 </MyList>
</MyReturnObject>
```

Is there some way to specify a text value for a given attribute ?
I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You mean for the given element? You *are* setting text values for attributes already.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class MyElement(ComplexModel):
    Name = XmlAttribute(String)
    Data = XmlData(Unicode)

class MyReturnObject(ComplexModel):
    MyList = Array(MyElement)
```

Usage:

```
from lxml import etree
from spyne.util.xml import get_object_as_xml

obj = MyReturnObject(MyList=[
    MyElement('value2', Name='Value1'),
    MyElement('value3', Name='Value2'),
])

elt = get_object_as_xml(obj, MyReturnObject)
print(etree.tostring(elt, pretty_print=True))
```

prints:

```
<MyReturnObject>
  <MyList>
    <MyElement Name="Value1">value2</MyElement>
    <MyElement Name="Value2">value3</MyElement>
  </MyList>
</MyReturnObject>
```